# Get uri segment in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, routes, segment

I'm trying to get uri segments in blade view using Laravel 5. 
I tried in this way:

```html
{{Request::segment(1)}}
```

But I'm getting this exception:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::base()

I tried to add:

```html
Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::class,
Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\ResponseFactory::class,
```

as providers, but what else should I add to aliases?

Comment: Those are not providers. Adding those to the providers array will throw exceptions, and you don't need to mess with the default providers or aliases at all to use `Request::segment(1)`.

Comment: Yes, I saw my mistake, I have used in my link URL::base instead of url(). Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned, providers may not be the way to do this. It's probably best to get the value you need in the Controller, and then pass it to the view.

In the controller:

```
//In your method
return response()->view('views.uri', ['uri_segment' => Request::segment(1)])
```

In the view:

```
{{ $uri_segment }}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: It's working, but now it's working when I call it in view direct. I had mistake with base url - not calling it properly.